# How do I make a stopwatch for discord bot?

Tags: time, while-loop, discord.py

I am a cuber and a programmer, I was helping a friend who suggested an idea in making a cubing bot! So we started on doing the scrambles for different cubes, and then we were trying to make a stopwatch for the bot, but when we run !stop in the channel, it doesn't stop the while loop, instead it just keeps on going!

```
import random
import discord
import os
import re
import keep_alive
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
  timer = 0.97
  limit = 600.00
  
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith("!3X3"):

    num = 0
    Scramble = []
    num2 = random.randint(15,26)
  
    while num < num2:
        notation = random.randint(1,18)
        num += 1
      
        if notation == 1:
          Scramble.append("U ")
        elif notation == 2:
          Scramble.append("U' ")
        elif notation == 3:
          Scramble.append("U2 ")
        elif notation == 4:
          Scramble.append("D ")
        elif notation == 5:
          Scramble.append("D' ")
        elif notation == 6:
          Scramble.append("D2 ")
        elif notation == 7:
          Scramble.append("R ")
        elif notation == 8:
          Scramble.append("R' ")
        elif notation == 9:
          Scramble.append("R2 ")
        elif notation == 10:
          Scramble.append("L ")
        elif notation == 11:
          Scramble.append("L' ")
        elif notation == 12:
          Scramble.append("L2 ")
        elif notation == 13:
          Scramble.append("F ")
        elif notation == 14:
          Scramble.append("F' ")
        elif notation == 15:
          Scramble.append("F2 ")
        elif notation == 16:
          Scramble.append("B ")
        elif notation == 17:
          Scramble.append("B' ")
        else: 
          Scramble.append("B2 ")
    
    ScrambleBR = (','.join(Scramble))
    ScrambleAF = re.sub(",","",ScrambleBR)

    ctx1 = await message.channel.send("`Generating 3X3 scramble . . .`")
    
    time.sleep(0.2)
    
    ScrambleRRL = re.sub("l' l'" or "l l","l2",ScrambleAF)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLL = re.sub("L' L'" or "L L","L2",ScrambleRRL)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLLL = re.sub("l2 l2" or "L2 L2" or "l' l' l' l'" or "L' L' L' L'" or "l l l l" or "L L L L" "l' l' l2" or "l2 l' l'" or "l l l2" or "l2 l l" or "L' L' L2" or "L2 L' L'" or "L L L2" or "L2 L L","",ScrambleRRLL)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRR = re.sub("r' r'" or "r r","r2",ScrambleRRLLL)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRR = re.sub("R' R'" or "R R","R2",ScrambleRRR)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRRR = re.sub("r2 r2" or "R2 R2" or "r' r' r' r'" or "R' R' R' R'" or "r r r r" or "R R R R" "r' r' r2" or "r2 r' r'" or "r r r2" or "r2 r r" or "R' R' R2" or "R2 R' R'" or "R R R2" or "R2 R R","",ScrambleRRRR)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRF = re.sub("f' f'" or "f f","f2",ScrambleRRRRR)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFF = re.sub("F' F'" or "F F","F2",ScrambleRRF)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFFF = re.sub("f2 f2" or "F2 F2" or "f' f' f' f'" or "F' F' F' F'" or "f f f f" or "F F F F" or "f' f' f2" or "f2 f' f'" or "f f f2" or "f2 f f" "F' F' F2" or "F2 F' F'" or "F F F2" or "F2 F F","",ScrambleRRFF)

    time.sleep(0.2)

    ScrambleRRD = re.sub("D' D'" or "D D","D2",ScrambleRRFFF)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRDD = re.sub("D' D' D' D'" or "D D D D","",ScrambleRRD)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRBB = re.sub("B' B'" or "B B","B2",ScrambleRRDD)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleFinal = re.sub("B2 B2" or "B' B' B' B'" or "B B B B" or "B' B' B2" or "B2 B' B'" or "B B B2" or "B2 B B","",ScrambleRRBB)
    
    await ctx1.edit(content = ScrambleFinal)

  if message.content.startswith("!2X2"):

    numm = 0
    Scramble2X2 = []
    numm2 = random.randint(8,10)
  
    while numm < numm2:
        notationn = random.randint(1,18)
      
        if notationn == 1:
          Scramble2X2.append("U ")
        elif notationn == 2:
          Scramble2X2.append("U' ")
        elif notationn == 3:
          Scramble2X2.append("U2 ")
        elif notationn == 4:
          Scramble2X2.append("D ")
        elif notationn == 5:
          Scramble2X2.append("D' ")
        elif notationn == 6:
          Scramble2X2.append("D2 ")
        elif notationn == 7:
          Scramble2X2.append("R ")
        elif notationn == 8:
          Scramble2X2.append("R' ")
        elif notationn == 9:
          Scramble2X2.append("R2 ")
        elif notationn == 10:
          Scramble2X2.append("L ")
        elif notationn == 11:
          Scramble2X2.append("L' ")
        elif notationn == 12:
          Scramble2X2.append("L2 ")
        elif notationn == 13:
          Scramble2X2.append("F ")
        elif notationn == 14:
          Scramble2X2.append("F' ")
        elif notationn == 15:
          Scramble2X2.append("F2 ")
        elif notationn == 16:
          Scramble2X2.append("B ")
        elif notationn == 17:
          Scramble2X2.append("B' ")
        else: 
          Scramble2X2.append("B2 ")
        numm += 1

    ScrambleBRR = (','.join(Scramble2X2))
    ScrambleAF2 = re.sub(",","",ScrambleBRR)
    ctx1 = await message.channel.send("`Generating 2X2 scramble . . .`")
    
    time.sleep(0.2)
    
    ScrambleRRL2 = re.sub("l' l'" or "l l","l2",ScrambleAF2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLL2 = re.sub("L' L'" or "L L","L2",ScrambleRRL2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLLL2 = re.sub("l2 l2" or "L2 L2" or "l' l' l' l'" or "L' L' L' L'" or "l l l l" or "L L L L" "l' l' l2" or "l2 l' l'" or "l l l2" or "l2 l l" or "L' L' L2" or "L2 L' L'" or "L L L2" or "L2 L L","",ScrambleRRLL2)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRR2 = re.sub("r' r'" or "r r","r2",ScrambleRRLLL2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRR2 = re.sub("R' R'" or "R R","R2",ScrambleRRR2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRRR2 = re.sub("r2 r2" or "R2 R2" or "r' r' r' r'" or "R' R' R' R'" or "r r r r" or "R R R R" "r' r' r2" or "r2 r' r'" or "r r r2" or "r2 r r" or "R' R' R2" or "R2 R' R'" or "R R R2" or "R2 R R","",ScrambleRRRR2)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRF2 = re.sub("f' f'" or "f f","f2",ScrambleRRRRR2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFF2 = re.sub("F' F'" or "F F","F2",ScrambleRRF2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFFF2 = re.sub("f2 f2" or "F2 F2" or "f' f' f' f'" or "F' F' F' F'" or "f f f f" or "F F F F" or "f' f' f2" or "f2 f' f'" or "f f f2" or "f2 f f" "F' F' F2" or "F2 F' F'" or "F F F2" or "F2 F F","",ScrambleRRFF2)

    time.sleep(0.2)

    ScrambleRRD2 = re.sub("D' D'" or "D D","D2",ScrambleRRFFF2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRDD2 = re.sub("D' D' D' D'" or "D D D D","",ScrambleRRD2)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRBB2 = re.sub("B' B'" or "B B","B2",ScrambleRRDD2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleFinal2 = re.sub("B2 B2" or "B' B' B' B'" or "B B B B" or "B' B' B2" or "B2 B' B'" or "B B B2" or "B2 B B","",ScrambleRRBB2)

    await ctx1.edit(content = ScrambleFinal2)

  if message.content.startswith("!4X4"):

    num4 = 0
    Scramble4X4 = []
    num24 = random.randint(43,47)
  
    while num4 < num24:
        notation4 = random.randint(1,36)
        num4 += 1
      
        if notation4 == 1:
          Scramble4X4.append("U ")
        elif notation4 == 2:
          Scramble4X4.append("U' ")
        elif notation4 == 3:
          Scramble4X4.append("U2 ")
        elif notation4 == 4:
          Scramble4X4.append("Uw ")
        elif notation4 == 5:
          Scramble4X4.append("Uw' ")
        elif notation4 == 6:
          Scramble4X4.append("Uw2 ")
        elif notation4 == 7:
          Scramble4X4.append("D ")
        elif notation4 == 8:
          Scramble4X4.append("D' ")
        elif notation4 == 9:
          Scramble4X4.append("D2 ")
        elif notation4 == 10:
          Scramble4X4.append("Dw ")
        elif notation4 == 11:
          Scramble4X4.append("Dw' ")
        elif notation4 == 12:
          Scramble4X4.append("Dw2 ")
        elif notation4 == 13:
          Scramble4X4.append("R ")
        elif notation4 == 14:
          Scramble4X4.append("R' ")
        elif notation4 == 15:
          Scramble4X4.append("R2 ")
        elif notation4 == 16:
          Scramble4X4.append("Rw ")
        elif notation4 == 17:
          Scramble4X4.append("Rw' ")
        elif notation4 == 18:
          Scramble4X4.append("Rw2 ")
        elif notation4 == 19:
          Scramble4X4.append("L ")
        elif notation4 == 20:
          Scramble4X4.append("L' ")
        elif notation4 == 21:
          Scramble4X4.append("L2 ")
        elif notation4 == 22:
          Scramble4X4.append("Lw ")
        elif notation4 == 23:
          Scramble4X4.append("Lw' ")
        elif notation4 == 24:
          Scramble4X4.append("Lw2 ")
        elif notation4 == 25:
          Scramble4X4.append("F ")
        elif notation4 == 26:
          Scramble4X4.append("F' ")
        elif notation4 == 27:
          Scramble4X4.append("F2 ")
        elif notation4 == 28:
          Scramble4X4.append("Fw ")
        elif notation4 == 29:
          Scramble4X4.append("Fw' ")
        elif notation4 == 30:
          Scramble4X4.append("Fw2 ")
        elif notation4 == 31:
          Scramble4X4.append("B' ")
        elif notation4 == 32:
          Scramble4X4.append("B ")
        elif notation4 == 33: 
          Scramble4X4.append("B2 ")  
        elif notation4 == 34:
          Scramble4X4.append("Bw ")
        elif notation4 == 35:
          Scramble4X4.append("Bw' ")
        else:
          Scramble4X4.append("Bw2 ")
    
    ScrambleBR4 = (','.join(Scramble4X4))
    ScrambleAR4 = re.sub(",","",ScrambleBR4)
    ctx4 = await message.channel.send("`Generating 4X4 scramble . . .`")

    time.sleep(0.2)
    
    ScrambleRRL4 = re.sub("l' l'" or "l l","l2",ScrambleAR4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLL4 = re.sub("L' L'" or "L L","L2",ScrambleRRL4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRLLL4 = re.sub("l2 l2" or "L2 L2" or "l' l' l' l'" or "L' L' L' L'" or "l l l l" or "L L L L" "l' l' l2" or "l2 l' l'" or "l l l2" or "l2 l l" or "L' L' L2" or "L2 L' L'" or "L L L2" or "L2 L L","",ScrambleRRLL4)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRR4 = re.sub("r' r'" or "r r","r2",ScrambleRRLLL4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRR4 = re.sub("R' R'" or "R R","R2",ScrambleRRR4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRRRR4 = re.sub("r2 r2" or "R2 R2" or "r' r' r' r'" or "R' R' R' R'" or "r r r r" or "R R R R" "r' r' r2" or "r2 r' r'" or "r r r2" or "r2 r r" or "R' R' R2" or "R2 R' R'" or "R R R2" or "R2 R R","",ScrambleRRRR4)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRF4 = re.sub("f' f'" or "f f","f2",ScrambleRRRRR4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFF4 = re.sub("F' F'" or "F F","F2",ScrambleRRF4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRFFF4 = re.sub("f2 f2" or "F2 F2" or "f' f' f' f'" or "F' F' F' F'" or "f f f f" or "F F F F" or "f' f' f2" or "f2 f' f'" or "f f f2" or "f2 f f" "F' F' F2" or "F2 F' F'" or "F F F2" or "F2 F F","",ScrambleRRFF4)

    time.sleep(0.2)

    ScrambleRRD4 = re.sub("D' D'" or "D D","D2",ScrambleRRFFF4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleRRDD4 = re.sub("D' D' D' D'" or "D D D D","",ScrambleRRD4)

    time.sleep(0.2)
  
    ScrambleRRBB4 = re.sub("B' B'" or "B B","B2",ScrambleRRDD4)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ScrambleFinal4 = re.sub("B2 B2" or "B' B' B' B'" or "B B B B" or "B' B' B2" or "B2 B' B'" or "B B B2" or "B2 B B","",ScrambleRRBB4)
    await ctx4.edit(content = ScrambleFinal4)

  if message.content.startswith("!pyra"):
    nump = 0
    ScramblePyra = []
    nump2 = random.randint(10,12)
  
    while nump < nump2:
      notationp = random.randint(1,18)
      
      if notationp == 1:
        ScramblePyra.append("U ")
      elif notationp == 2:
        ScramblePyra.append("U' ")
      elif notationp == 3:
        ScramblePyra.append("U2 ")
      elif notationp == 4:
        ScramblePyra.append("R ")
      elif notationp == 5:
        ScramblePyra.append("R' ")
      elif notationp == 6:
        ScramblePyra.append("R2 ")
      elif notationp == 7:
        ScramblePyra.append("L ")
      elif notationp == 8:
        ScramblePyra.append("L' ")
      elif notationp == 9:
        ScramblePyra.append("L2 ")
      elif notationp == 10:
        ScramblePyra.append("r ")
      elif notationp == 11:
        ScramblePyra.append("r' ")
      elif notationp == 12:
        ScramblePyra.append("l ")
      elif notationp == 13:
        ScramblePyra.append("l' ")
      elif notationp == 14:
        ScramblePyra.append("b ")
      elif notationp == 15:  
        ScramblePyra.append("b' ")
      elif notationp == 16:
        ScramblePyra.append("B' ")
      elif notationp == 17:
        ScramblePyra.append("B ")
      else: 
        ScramblePyra.append("B2 ")
      nump += 1

    ScrambleBRRp = (','.join(ScramblePyra))
    ScrambleFinal3 = re.sub(",","",ScrambleBRRp)
    await message.channel.send(ScrambleFinal3)

  if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
      await message.channel.send(timer)
  
  if message.content.startswith("!start"):

    timerm = await message.channel.send("`Time will be here`")
    
    ready = await message.channel.send("**3**")
    time.sleep(1)
    set = await message.channel.send("**2**")
    time.sleep(1)
    go = await message.channel.send("**1**")
    time.sleep(1)
    GO = await message.channel.send("**GO!**")
    time.sleep(0.97)
    
    while timer < limit:
      time.sleep(0.01)
      timer += 0.01
      print(timer) #for testing if stopwatch works
      if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
        c = await message.channel.send(timer)
        break
      
keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

This is the part we are struggling with

```
  if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
      await message.channel.send(timer)
  
  if message.content.startswith("!start"):

    timerm = await message.channel.send("`Time will be here`")
    
    ready = await message.channel.send("**3**")
    time.sleep(1)
    set = await message.channel.send("**2**")
    time.sleep(1)
    go = await message.channel.send("**1**")
    time.sleep(1)
    GO = await message.channel.send("**GO!**")
    time.sleep(0.97)
    
    while timer < limit:
      time.sleep(0.01)
      timer += 0.01
      print(timer) #for testing if stopwatch works
      if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
        c = await message.channel.send(timer)
        break
```

I have been looking around the internet for answers, some are kind of similar but not what I am looking for. I hope someone can solve this question, because you might change cubing bots forever!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

This is called whenever a message is sent. `message` is passed as a parameter, and you can then use it.

Now, say the user calls `"!start"`.

We will then enter this if-statement:

```
if message.content.startswith("!start"):
```

And after some more code, this will be run:

```
while timer < limit:
      #some code
      if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
        c = await message.channel.send(timer)
        break
```

The problem here is with `if message.content.startswith("!stop"):`. Nothing here actually **reads** a new message; this if statement is being run with the same `message`, which starts with `"!start"`. In this *coroutine*, the message starts with `"!start"`, and therefore we will never enter this if statement, as it definitely does not start with `"!stop"`.

Now, when `"!stop"` is actually called, it is in a *new* coroutine of `on_message(message)`, which means it does not interact with the old `while` loop. Instead, in the new coroutine this code is run:

```
await message.channel.send(timer)
```

The `while` loop continues, meaning that your timer keeps on going.

What this means is, calling `"!stop"` will never break the loop as it is done in a separate *coroutine*, though it will print out the contents of `timer`.

---

You can experiment with a few ways of fixing this. You can open a new [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for the while loop of the timer, and [kill the thread](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) when the timer ends.

As far as I know, this is the most elegant way to do it, although I'm excited to see what people can come up with in the comments. I'll add those to my answer.